# Conditional Statement seems to not get the value of a variable in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
 else:
    for i in hand1.cardList:
        if i.value==1: # if there is an ace in the hand

            print "Soft Sum: %d "% hand1.soft_sum()
            if hand1.soft_sum()==21:
                outcome="player_black_jack"             

        print out_come
```

This code checks to see if there is a card of value 1 in `hand1.cardList`.
If there is a card of value 1 then the code gets a soft sum value from `hand1.soft_sum()`. The code then prints out the correct value of the class method`hand1.soft_sum()`. The code then tests to see if the `hand1.soft_sum()` is equal to`21`...if it is equal to to `21` then the code should set out_come to "black_jack". I have ran this code and even when the `hand1.soft_sum()` IS equal to 21 I get this:

```
***HAND 1***  
♣ K ♠ A 
Hard Sum: 11  
Soft Sum: 21
```

It is supposed to then print "player_black_jack"
But it does not.

Comment: `outcome` and `out_come` are two different variables.

Answer (score 0):

try converting it to int manually like so:

```
 else:
    for i in hand1.cardList:
        if i.value==1: # if there is an ace in the hand

            print "Soft Sum: %d "% hand1.soft_sum()
            if int(hand1.soft_sum())==21:
                out_come="player_black_jack"             

        print out_come
```